# HTML 5 video subtitles supporting

Tags: javascript, browser, html5-video, video.js, subtitle

Some subtitles which I'm adding to video player for movies and shows don't supported with browser and because of that we see this picture.
[image]

It's required to add language font in browser for show those languages in correct way but users whose gonna watch movies don't know how to add fonts in their browsers and it's not best solution to make them do that.

I'm adding tracks(subtitles) using [video.js](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-video-tracks.html)

How I can solve subtitle font broke issue or if it's not possible then I need to hide them from subtitles list, how I can check subtitle font supported or not ?

Part from code where I'm adding subtitles

```
playbackData.subtitles.forEach(function (subtitle) {
        vjsPlayer.addRemoteTextTrack({
            src: subtitle.url,
            kind: 'subtitles',
            label: subtitle.language,
        }, true);
    });
```

Comment: Sounds more like an encoding issue than a font one. Could you link to an example subtitle file where you experience that issue?

Comment: Yes sure for example this one for Korean subtitles https://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/src-api/vrf-19f70c66/filead/1956489568.gz

Comment: Ah so it's not an encoding issue, I was wrong? This file is correctly encoded as UTF-8. But it's not quite clear why your users would have to install a new font, though I must admit I'm not entirely sure either how this library renders the subtitles. Certainly your Korean users will already have a Hangul font installed on their system. Do you think this would fail there to? Can you read 테스트?

Comment: I found the problem, it's connected with my operation system. I use Debian 10 buster and it's just don't support Korean language. About Hebrew language when convert subtitle from srt to vtt with nodejs script `npm install srt-to-vtt` it's convert with right unicode. But php convertor https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles don't convert  correctly.

Answer (score 0):

use your language of subtitle, ex: `language: 'en'`

*For supported language translations, please see the languages folder (/lang) (https://github.com/videojs/video.js/tree/main/lang) folder located in the Video.js root and refer to the languages guide (https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-languages.html) for more information on languages in Video.js.*

Comment: It's not helping and also it's optional https://docs.videojs.com/html5#addRemoteTextTrack

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it's connected with my operation system. I use Debian 10 buster OS and it's just don't support `Korean` language.

About `Hebrew` language when I convert subtitle from `srt` to `vtt` with NodeJS script( `npm install srt-to-vtt` ) it's convert with right unicode.

But PHP convertor [github.com/mantas-done/subtitles](http://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles) don't convert correctly some languages.

So if you will have a problem with subtitles

1. Check subtitles on other Operational systems(Windows, MacOS and etc).
2. If there subtitles don't work again then you can check your convertor and maybe you need to try other convertors  as well. I suggest you use NodeJS convertors.